# Sed поиск и печать части строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash

Добрый вечер, есть список строк типа

`[I] x11-wm/awesome (3.5-r1{tbz2}@02/26/2013): A dynamic floating and tiling window` manager
Как с помощью sed выбрать только x11-wm/awesome?
Я не совсем понимаю..по идеи должен быть шаблон типа ([a-z]+/+[a-z]) и печать только соответствия..
А как правильно это сделать...еще не грамотен в этом

вот полный спиок до http://bpaste.net/show/84907/
и как должно быть после

- x11-proto/xf86bigfontproto
- x11-proto/xf86dgaproto
- x11-proto/xf86driproto
- x11-proto/xf86rushproto
- x11-proto/xf86vidmodeproto
- x11-proto/xineramaproto
- x11-proto/xproto
- x11-terms/rxvt-unicode
- x11-terms/xterm
- x11-themes/gnome-icon-theme
- x11-themes/gtk-chtheme

Comment: Почитал немного о sed вроде получилось
sed 's/^.*\] //; s/ (.*$//'
Но может кто то предложет лучьший вариант...

Comment: @zinteco В комментариях код надо выделять в обратные слеши, иначе будет непонятено.

У меня получилось страшновато, может лучше будет?

    sed -n '/[0-9a-z-]\+\/[a-z]\+/{s,\([0-9a-z-]\+/[a-z]\+\).*,#\1,;s,.*#,,;p}'

Т.е. сначала поиск строки, затем замена хвоста с предшествующим `#`, затем удаление до `#` и печать. (самого этого символа в строке не должно быть). Нежадных регэкспов что-то не нашёл.

Comment: @alexlz почти работает, он обрезает некоторые названи пакетов.
например x11-proto/xf86bigfontproto отображает x11-proto/xf. Это из за цифр наверное

Comment: Тогда нужно добавить цифры. Если информация должна начинаться с `x11-`, то ситуации проще:

       cat file.txt | sed -n '/x11-[0-9a-z]\+\/[a-z0-9]\+/{s,.*\(x11-[0-9a-z]\+/[a-z0-9]\+\).*,\1,;p}' | sort | uniq


`sort | uniq` -- для устранения дублирования.

Answer (score 1):

Этот вариант работает как в gnu sed так и в bsd sed. Руками развернуты разделители колонок(whitespace)

```
sed 's/^[^\ ]*[\ \t]\([^\ \t]*\).*/\1/'
```

пример:

```
echo '[I] x11-wm/awesome (3.5-r1{tbz2}@02/26/2013): A dynamic floating and tiling window' | sed 's/^[^\ ]*[\ \t]\([^\ \t]*\).*/\1/'
x11-wm/awesome
```

Comment: Да, конечно, вопрос про sed. / А на практике я бы не задумываясь написал `awk '{ print $2 }'`  (надеюсь автор *вопроса*  @zinteco  увидит).